# Counting word length and frequency in a text file

Tags: python, dictionary

I am running Python 3.4.X

I would like to create function which takes a string as input (where the string is the name of a file) and returns a dictionary. The dictionary should have key/value pairs where keys are integers that correspond to word lengths and the values are the number of words that appear in the file with that length. I just really have no idea how to do this and I would greatly appreciate any help with this. Thank you!

I want the final output to look something like this { 3:5, 4:2, 5:1, 8:1, 10:1}

Comment: Try your homework and include attempts before asking!

Comment: Is it a class assignment? If so are there restrictions?

Comment: There are no restrictions

Comment: Have you looked at other existing questions first? I'm sure there are already dozens similar ones...

Comment: I found 1 question that was the same but no one had answered it.

Comment: loop through each word of file/string..if word is not in dictonary insert it with value 1 else if it already exists increase the value of it by 1

Comment: Browse through  http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/topics.  It has common SO Python Q&A's categorized.

Comment: Will do thank you everyone for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example that you can try. The example assumes that the file read has a new word at each line

```
def create_dict(name):
  ret = {}
  if name:
    with open(name,'r') as fd:
        for line in fd.readlines():
            line = line.replace("\n","")
            if ret.get(len(line),None) == None:
                ret[len(line)] = 1
            else:
                ret[len(line)] += 1
  return ret
```

returns `{8: 1, 2: 1, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 1}` for the following inout file data

```
hello
world
from
python
to
test
scenario
```

Comment: Thank you so much this helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you read through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html#the-python-tutorial) and practice the examples, you will start to get ideas.  You will need to [open a file](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files), [iterate](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) over the words in it, [determine the length](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len), if the length is already in the [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) then add 1 to it, if not make a new key:value pair with the value = 1.